# Diode and Op Amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, diodes, voltage-divider

[image]

Can you help me finding the expression of Vo(Vi) and graphing Vo(t)? I have simulated it in multisim but i can  not understand when the diode passes current or not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clearly, this is a [homework](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).  What were you able to figure out so far?

Comment: @NickAlexeev i thought it was allowed. Sorry. My doubt is when V.red-Vi is positive, negative or zero?

Comment: i think that Vi=Vred=Vo. Is it right??? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For homework questions showing no extensive efforts we only give hints, not complete solutions.

Assuming the op-amp can be considered ideal (as it is usual with this kind of homework questions), keep in mind the golden rules of ideal op-amps:

- *If negative feedback is in action* the voltages at the inverting (\$V^{-}\$) and non-inverting (\$V^{+}\$) input will be the same, i.e.  \$\quad V^{-}=\; V^{+}\$.
- The inputs of the op-amp draw no current whatsoever.

Another hint: the op-amp+diode part behaves as an ideal rectifier.

**EDIT** (prompted by a comment)

Keep in mind that the circuit is non-linear and it changes its behavior as the sawtooth generator changes its output voltage.

The diode is not always on. When it is on, negative feedback is ensured, so golden rule 1 applies. There are times when that diode is off, thus there is no feedback and the op-amp saturates. In this latter situation the voltages at the inputs of the op-amp are not the same!

Try to understand under which conditions the diode turns off and how it affects the other quantities.

**EDIT** (providing more clues, since the OP was probably misled by the simulation program)

When the sawtooth generator puts out a positive voltage, the opamp output is driven towards positive voltages, this makes the diode conduct and provide negative feedback. In this situation golden rule #1 is valid.

When the sawtooth generator goes negative, the opamp output is driven towards negative voltages, thus driving the diode into cut-off. No negative feedback here. This means that the opamp output saturates to negative rail (but this is not important here). The important thing is that in this situation the diode is cut-off, therefore disconnecting the opamp from the output (the inverting input draws no current thus is virtually disconnected as well). Can you see now what drives the output of the circuit?

Comment: But if V-=V+, Vo=V-. I can not go any further. as i commented

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence...but i don't understand what happens in the circuit. I have tried to make changes to the circuit in multisim and without the diode i see what i expectd but with the diode i don't even expect anything.(of course i know what a diode does but in this case i can´t). would you mind to explain me?

Comment: @the funny output voltage you get from the simulation is probably due to a non-ideal op-amp. Try to see if multisim has a part that simulates an ideal op-amp.

Comment: An advice: try [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) as a circuit simulator. Less frills, but a real industry standard, gives good results and it's free and lightweight.

Comment: Tell me if it is true that if the diode passes Vo=V+ and if not Vo=2V. Knowing that we know that the opamp is a voltage follower when the diode passes (Vin>2) and is 2 otherwise??Thanks for your kindness and for your time.